# Fraction in other bases

Tags: fractions, number-systems

How to convert a base 10 fraction into fraction in other bases?. For example base 10 fraction 17/94, How we convert this 17/94 into base 2 fraction ?

Comment: Can you please give an example of a base 2 fraction?

Comment: 100110/1000000001101, with calculation is also performed in base-2 fashion

Comment: "Calculation performed in base-2 fashion" does not make sense. $38$ divided by $4109$ is $\frac{38}{4109}$ whether you *write* it as `100110/1000000001101` or as `38 ÷ 4109` or as `XXXVIII DIVISA PER MMMMCIX`. The calculations are the same; the only thing that changed is how you wrote them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just convert the numerator and denominator to base-2 and write that as your fraction?
$$
  \bigg(\frac{17}{94}\bigg)_{10} =
  \frac{17_{10}}{94_{10}} = 
  \frac{00010001_2}{01011110_2} = 
  \bigg(\frac{00010001}{01011110}\bigg)_2 
$$
If this is not what you are asking for, you should provide more details/context in your question.

Comment: Are you sure they both have equal value ?

Comment: They have equal value in the notation I am using. This really comes down to how you *define* what it means to represent a fraction in a certain base. I supposed that we say $17/94$ is a base-10 fraction just because its numerator and denominator are represented in base-10. Converting the fraction to base-2 is then only a matter of converting the numerator and denominator to base-2. If you mean something else by "convert $17/94$ to base-2", your post should specify this.

Comment: Numbers exist independently of how we write them. There is a number that can be written $17_{10}$ or $10001_2$ depending on which base you want to use. So yes, the numerators in the equation have the same value, because they are the same number written two different ways. The same reasoning applies to the denominators.

Comment: I mean if that base-2 fraction is converted into base-2 decimal expansion (with calculation is also performed in base-2 fashion),and that base-2 decimal expansion is converted into the base-10 decimal expansion,then they both have exactly the same value. :)

Comment: That depends on how you do the "conversion". Usually when we say we are converting from base 10 to base 2 representation, we mean we are doing the conversion that leaves the *numerical value* unchanged.  $10111_2 = 23_{10}$ because $10111_2$ and $23_{10}$ are *different ways of writing the same number*.  So yes, if you convert a base-2 fraction (as written in this answer) into a base-2 decimal so that the numerical value remains unchanged, and then you convert that base-2 decimal into a base-10 decimal so that the value remains unchanged, then yes, they will all have exactly the same value.

Comment: Note that when you write $17/94$ as a decimal fraction (digits followed by decimal point followed by more digits), it has an infinitely repeating group of digits at the end. If you do not account for the repeating digits, but consider only a finite number of digits, you have not written $17/94$ exactly, so already it is not "equal value" even before you consider the binary representation. But if you account for the repeating digits in both bases then you can write the exact same value in each case.

Comment: @DavidK,note that that base-2 fraction is converted into base-2 decimal with calculation being performed in that base-2 too.And when we convert that result into base-10 decimal,and voila we have exactly the same value ;)